# what to do when a tag is firing on google tag manager and not showing up in debug view

Tags: google-analytics-4

what to do when a tag is firing on google tag manager and not showing up in debug view

I have tried creating event again, added a debugger extension, tried using developer tools network

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to confirm a few things first:

1. Check that the debug_mode parameter is being passed in GTM so that it can appear in the DebugView report.
2. If you have any filters applied to internal/dev traffic that may be excluding the events from showing up you may need to disable it.
3. Check to confirm that you have selected the correct debug device in the dropdown. If you have multiple people debugging events you'll need to select your correct device.